# How to Convert String To DateTime in java

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime, datepicker

I am trying to store date in sql server 2005
i am used "datetime" data type in sql server
and in java program i am passing string as date

ex.

```
String DateStr = "12/12/2013";

Date d = new Date();
java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

String sql = "INSERT INTO info (date) VALUES ( ? )";

try {
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setDate(1, d1);
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
     }
```

the above code is working...but i want to use **String DateStr = "12/12/2013"; 
insted of d.getTime()** bcoz i passed date as string to java function by using jquery datepicker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your String to a date and then use that date.

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(DateStr); // This throws a ParseException

// Rest everything stays pretty much the same
java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
...
```

Comment: Sorry For too late....It's store the current date like (thursday 28-11-2013) not DateStr

Comment: the `DateStr` is the String holding your date. what format does it have?

Comment: in sql server 2005 i am using datetime as my datatype and want to store String DateStr="25/11/2013"; such string into datetime but failed

Answer (score 0):

```
public long convertLong(String value) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date getDate = null;
    long returnDate = 0l;
    try {
        getDate = (Date) formatter.parse(value);
        returnDate = getDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

Input: `12/12/2013` 
Output: `1386786600000`

Comment: and how to use it to store in database

Comment: Like you are doing `java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());` I'm not sure but will work. I just gave you solution for getting `d.getTime()` from your `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Have you tried like `java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(convertLong("12/12/2013"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

First convert string in **datetime object** than you can directly pass d1 to your code

```
String DateStr = "12/12/2013";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy ");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(DateStr);
String sql = "INSERT INTO info (date) VALUES ( dt )";
try {
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setDate(1, d1);
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
     } 
catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
     }
```

Comment: Thanx for replying but it shows 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "28/11/2013" is too short'

Comment: and if i use pstmt.setDate(1, dt); it shows 'DateTime CanNot be converted to Date'